# Android Studio cross-compiling static library.

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, static-libraries

Well, I'm trying to cross-compile a static library (.a format) for Android with this line:
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/build --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--disable-shared

When It's compiling, i get this error: 
configure: error: libpthread not found!

I'm using Android Studio terminal and Mac OS X.
I've used this tutorial, too:
http://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to specify the libpthread position like

```
LD_FLAGS="-L/path/to/libpthread" ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/build --host=arm-linux-androideabi \ --disable-shared
```